# POSIX path prompt, with spaces? Applescript objc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, unix, applescript

I already know how they work, for example ~/Library/Application\ Support.
But thats not the problem, lets say i have a script that removes a file through terminal

```
Rm -rf /path/
```

I want a prompt so that i can choose the file to remove, heres the code for that

```
 set thePath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "prompt")
```

I have done that, and when i want to perform rm -rf on ~/Desktop/Delete this file/

It says

```
~/Desktop/Delete file not found
~/Desktop/this   file not found
```

And so on, I'm not typing it in myself because i just choose a folder, but for some reason applescriptobjtc doesn't know how to handle spaces itself why? How would i run the rm -rf command on a path with spaces in it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set thePath to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "prompt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the rm shell command inside a do shell script command in Applescript? If so, show your do shell script line, which is where the problem is.
Most likely, you simply need to specify the quoted form of thePath.

```
set thePath to (choose folder with prompt "prompt")
do shell script "rm " & (quoted form of POSIX path of thePath)
```